# CPU temperature real time with python default libraries

Tags: python, sensors, temperature

How can I detect CPU temperature and RAM temperature in real time with python default libraries?

Comment: AFAIK, there aren't any standard library modules that can interact with the hardware sensors. Would you consider something like `os.system('sensors -uA')` as a solution? Why are you specifically asking about default libraries anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Getting CPU temperature using Python?](/q/2440511/4518341) (focused on Linux), [Accessing CPU temperature in python](/q/3262603/4518341) (focused on Windows), [Get CPU and GPU Temp using Python Windows](/q/62617789/4518341)

Comment: Thanks for esplicative links... I had already read programs in links... I had tryed check CPU temperature with the following methods: import wmi and import clr but in the same case i had an error in debug... I wanted to go through internal libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that such kind of function or module is standard.

You can install the package `psutil` to use this function (`pip install --user psutil`):

```py
import psutil

psutil.sensors_temperatures()
```

Otherwise,if you really don't want to install non standard packages, you might find information somwhere on your computer, for example on Linux:

```sh
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

> You can read those kind of files directly in your Python code but I don't think that's a good practice as it's not cross platform !