# Trying to avoid that my PC needs to shutdown while running CPU demanding programs. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, cpu, temperature

My computer has an automatic protection system that prevents it from overheating, so when it reaches a certain temperature it protects itself by shutting down. I like this because I made a significant investment in my computer. However, I would like to find out before these thermal events happen. To be able to save my work. In a first phase, I am trying to get the temperature and then my plan is to set an audible alarm in "yellow".

However, I haven't managed to get my CPU temperature yet. What am I doing wrong?

Following is my current code:

```
import cpuinfo
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init

# Inicializar colorama
init(autoreset=True)

# Función para obtener la temperatura de la CPU
def get_cpu_temperature():
    try:
        info = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()
        temperature = info.get('temperature', None)
        return temperature
    except Exception as e:
        return f"{Fore.CYAN}Error al obtener temperatura: {e}"

# Función para mostrar la temperatura con colores
def display_temperature(temperature):
    if temperature is None:
        print(f"{Fore.CYAN}No se pudo obtener la temperatura.")
    else:
        temp_str = f"Temperatura: {temperature}°C"
        if temperature < 40:
            print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{temp_str}")
        elif temperature < 70:
            print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}{temp_str}")
        else:
            print(f"{Fore.RED}¡ALERTA! {temp_str}")

# Obtener la temperatura de la CPU
temperature = get_cpu_temperature()

# Mostrar la temperatura o el mensaje de error con colores
display_temperature(temperature)
```

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing? What kind of research into your problem have you done? What specific problem do you think you’re having—it’s best to ask about that rather than the more general “what’s wrong with my problem” question here. The latter is off topic for SO and likely to be heavily downvoted or closed in its current form.

Comment: FWIW, if it's possible for your computer to overheat simply from using its maximum potential, then your thermal system is simply insufficient. That's something that should be fixed in hardware, not software.

Comment: What hardware do you have?  Most x86 systems from the past decade or more should just throttle their clock speeds as they get close to thermal limits.

Comment: Do you think it might be a good idea to make a significant investment in a better cooling solution? :-) Things like bigger/more fans, better case, or simply (a cheaper solution of) opening up the case and clearing out dust/gunk with a compressed air can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing CPU temperature in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3262603) for Windows, or more generically perhaps [CPU temperature real time with python default libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71187758) .  IDK if any of the answers are good on questions that come up when I google `site:stackoverflow.com python cpu temperature`, but there are a lot of them, and would be a better start than randomly guessing an attribute name in the cpuinfo library.

Comment: `find out before these thermal events happen. To be able to save my work` does your computer use 100% CPU just for editing your code

Comment: @rioV8: Huh?  You could be editing something while a computation is running, thanks to the magic of multi-tasking OSes which have been a thing for over half a century.  Or they could be wanting to save partial progress of their computation so it can resume from there.  Or even better, suspend any active tasks until the computer cools off so it *doesn't* reset in the first place.

Comment: @PeterCordes if they design a computer that will shut it self of due to overheating when using 100% CPU is a bad designed computer, It should stay in the air with 100% CPU no matter how long it runs. Otherwise some Google Date centers would shutdown often when it was training there Deep Learning networks, some of these trainings take days. The result may be that the computer makes a lot of noise to get rid of the produced heat but it will keep working. Editing files with 100% CPU is near impossible with a GUI editor, maybe vim would work.

Comment: there are desktop tools that show the CPU temperature in the desktop status line/task bar

Comment: @rioV8: Yes, that's what I and others commented above, that modern CPUs can just throttle their clock speeds to stay below thermal limits even with bad cooling.  Things would have to be very extreme, like heat sink fallen off or not making thermal contact with the chip, *and* maybe no case fans, for a normal modern x86 system to hard power itself instead of just running slow.

Comment: @rioV8: *Editing files with 100% CPU is near impossible with a GUI editor, maybe vim would work.* - That's not normal.  Freezing GUI apps usually only happens when programs are using nearly all the RAM, thrashing the swap space.  On my Linux desktop, I can have an ffmpeg encode in the background using all 8 logical cores on my Skylake desktop, and at most my web browser is a little less snappy.  (Or limiting it to just 4 threads, leaving the other logical core free on each physical core and using less DRAM bandwidth and it's barely noticeable.)  Windows / MacOS should be similar.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe ffmpeg sets the calculation threads to a nice priority so UI processes gets handled first and you have a responsive computer, that does the video stuff when there is nothing else to do

Comment: @rioV8: No, not unless I do that manually (which I sometimes do but it doesn't make a noticeable difference to interactive use, only if I had other short computations like compiling something).  An editor or browser only needs a tiny fraction of the total CPU time, and if it's been idle for a while (like between keystrokes) it will get a timeslice pretty much right away.  (On Linux, even if I ran ffmpeg at max non-realtime priority like `nice -19`, it still wouldn't starve other tasks.  It might on Windows, but not with ffmpeg and the editor at normal priority.)

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get:

> No se pudo obtener la temperatura.

The most likely reason for that is because temperature is *not* one of the items available, assuming you're using `py-cpuinfo` as I am. The available items are shown [here](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo) (see under "Fields" heading).

I suggest you run the following code to figure out what it returns for you:

```py
import cpuinfo, pprint
pprint.pprint(cpuinfo.get_cpu_info())
```

On my system, for example, I get:

```py
{'arch': 'X86_64',
 'arch_string_raw': 'x86_64',
 'bits': 64,
 'brand_raw': 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz',
 'count': 2,
 'cpuinfo_version': [9, 0, 0],
 'cpuinfo_version_string': '9.0.0',
 'family': 6,
 'flags': ['3dnowprefetch',
           'abm',
           'adx',
           'aes',
           'apic',
           ... lots of irrelevant stuff removed.
           'xsaves',
           'xtopology'],
 'hz_actual': [2592007000, 0],
 'hz_actual_friendly': '2.5920 GHz',
 'hz_advertised': [2600000000, 0],
 'hz_advertised_friendly': '2.6000 GHz',
 'l1_data_cache_size': 65536,
 'l1_instruction_cache_size': 65536,
 'l2_cache_associativity': 6,
 'l2_cache_line_size': 256,
 'l2_cache_size': 524288,
 'l3_cache_size': 12582912,
 'model': 158,
 'python_version': '3.8.10.final.0 (64 bit)',
 'stepping': 10,
 'vendor_id_raw': 'GenuineIntel'}
```

---

In terms of how to rectify this situation, you'll probably need to specify your environment as accessing temperatures is not necessarily something that's easy to do cross-platform. For example, you would probably use `wmic` on Windows, or locate the correct `/proc` or `/sys` files under Linux.

> And, just as an aside, if your machine is shutting down due to overheating, you should probably focus on fixing the root cause of *that* (the overheating) rather than trying to live with it by reacting to warnings.
>
> The cheapest solution is probably to invest in a compressed air can, opening up the case, and clearing out accumulated dust/gunk from fans (CPU and case) and the case ventilation points. Or, better yet, blast that air everywhere in the case to clear it out.
>
> If that still doesn't fix it, you may want to look into a better case or more grunty fans. Or just more fans in general.
>
> I realise they're not programming solutions but, to be honest, your machine probably *shouldn't* be shutting down due to overheating. Most modern hardware will simply throttle the CPU until it cools down a little. Better to run slow than not run at all.

Comment: These are all things it can get from the `cpuid` instruction (except maybe `hz_actual`), but CPU temperature is a separate thing.

Comment: https://github.com/brendangregg/msr-cloud-tools/blob/master/cputemp is code to read CPU temperature from an Intel CPU.  It comes from an MSR (Model Specific Register), so unlike `cpuid` it's not something you can do from user-space, because even reading them is a privileged instruction.  You have to go through the kernel.  (e.g. via Linux's MSR driver which exposes MSRs to user-space, or via an OS interface for cpu-temperature if there is one.)